# AIX numeric time zone offset

Tags: aix, timezone-offset

Is there an OS command to display the numeric time zone offset in AIX 7.1?  Other Unix systems have the "date +%z" command that will return it (-0400 for example).  AIX will return its abbreviation (EDT for example) instead.

Comment: I don't know the 'solution', but installing GNU-date (as 'gdate' to avoid confusion) would be a workaround.  

It also knows useful tricks like gdate -d "10 days ago"

Answer (score 1):

GNU's `date` is usually installed in /usr/linux/bin on AIX versions later than 6.x.  Unless your Sysadmin had some specific reason not to install those packages by default, they are likely to be there.

If its not installed, IBM provides the [Linux Toolbox for AIX](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/).

After its installed, a quick `alias date=/usr/linux/bin/date` would give you GNU date by default.